# User to user request dialog not appearing in my application

Tags: javascript, facebook, jquery, url, dialog

My url works fine when I put it directly in the address bar, but when executing the code below, it gets to the error.

```
$.ajax({
                        type: 'GET',
                        url: 'http://www.facebook.com/dialog/apprequests?app_id='+appid+'&message=hello&redirect_uri='+redirect_url,
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('success');                                   
                        },
                        error: function (error){
                            alert('error');
                        }
                    });
```

Why is it not working from my Java Script code?

Comment: It's probably due to cross-origin resource sharing restrictions. What exactly is the information jQuery is giving you as first and second parameter in the `error` handler? P.S.: I don't work with Facebook, so I don't know if they support this. Regardless, still give us the additional information...

Comment: "readyState":0,"responseText":"","status":0,"statusText":"error"

Comment: readyState 0 means usually something didn't go right. It's the initial readyState code and means "initialized". It can happen if the server does not return any headers, i.e. refuses to answer. Which supports my hypothesis that the URL you are trying to access is restricted to Facebook only... Maybe somebody could find some information from the Facebook API and documentation stuff, but I have to leave now. Good luck.